# Javascript properties to jquery variables

Tags: javascript

I'm making a little script right now and one of the inputs for an arg of the main function is an element. In order to make sure that raw JS works for this stuff I'm doing `theelement.value` to get the variable's value. Unfortunately, that doesn't work if `thelement` is a jquery function, like `$('#foo')`. Some other reasons I need this kind of compatibility is that I need access to `theelement.style`, once again something jquery doesn't support. I know there are jquery workarounds for these (`.css(), .val()` etc.) but if I use those, then regular js inputs (`document.getElementbyId('foo')`) won't work. Is there any way to use one "property" and make it universal against all inputs of elements (including stuff from libraries like prototype and Dojo)?

Comment: I'm really unclear on what you're asking. That said, all of those libraries should let you access raw elements that their APIs wrap. For example, if you want to get the one (raw) DOM element by ID with jQuery, you can use `$("#foo")[0]`.

Comment: Second @millimoose suggestion. Translate all non-DOM element params into the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to make everything universal.

If you want to work on DOM elements, the input needs to be DOM elements and the framworks all have ways of getting the DOM elements out. You can not magically make a script that works with any library out there, that is why generic plugins normally have library specific extensions to add support.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a function that takes an argument and you have issues when you pass different types as that argument:

```
function doSomething(element) {
    // do something with element
}
```

You've mentioned that you want element to sometimes be a jQuery object and sometimes just a DOM object and then you also mentioned other libraries too (prototype, Dojo).

First off, your problem will go away entirely if you just call your function with a consistent type.  The simplest type here that is available in all libraries is a DOM element.  So, if you just enforce that element is passed as a DOM object reference and not a jQuery object or any other library object, then your problem will go away entirely.  If the caller is using some other library and then wants to call your function, they can always get the DOM object from that library and pass the actual DOM object.  For example, in jQuery, you can get a DOM object like this `$("#foo").get(0)

If you want to make it more universal and accept multiple types, then you have to write code to detect each type that might be passed and get the DOM object out of each type so you can then process them all identically.  For example, if you wanted to detect either a jQuery object of a DOM object, you could do so like this:

```
function doSomething(element) {
    // normalize element to be just a DOM object
    // if it's a jQuery object, then reach in to get the first DOM object
    if (element.jquery) {
        element = element.get(0);
    }

    // do something with element here which is a DOM object
}
```

If you wanted to detect objects from other libraries too, then you'd have to write similar detection code for each other library and get the actual DOM object out of that other library's object.